# Check for anonymous functions in PHP arrays?

Tags: php, anonymous-function, method-chaining, magic-methods

How can we check for anonymous functions inside PHP arrays?

Example:

```
$array = array('callback' => function() {
    die('calls back');
});
```

Can we then just simply use `in_array`, and to something like this:

```
if( in_array(function() {}, $array) ) {
    // Yes! There is an anonymous function inside my elements.
} else {
    // Nop! There are no anonymous function inside of me.
}
```

I'm experimenting with method chaining and PHP's Magic Methods, and I've come to the point where I provide some functions anonymously, and just want to check if they are defined, but I wish not to loop through the object, nor to use `gettype`, or anything similar.

Comment: doubt it. in_array looks for values only, and each closure is going to have a different value, even though the "code" is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the array by checking if the value is an instance of `Closure`:

```
$array = array( 'callback' => function() { die( 'callback'); });
$anon_fns = array_filter( $array, function( $el) { return $el instanceof Closure; });
if( count( $anon_fns) == 0) { // Assumes count( $array) > 0
    echo 'No anonymous functions in the array';
} else {
    echo 'Anonymous functions exist in the array';
}
```

Pretty much, just check if the element of the array is an instance of `Closure`. If it is, you have a callable type.

Answer (score 1):

Nickb's answer is great for figuring out if it is an anonymous function, but you may also use is_callable to figure out if it is any type of function ( probably more safe to assume )

For example

```
$x = function() { die(); }
$response = action( array( $x ) );
...
public function action( $array ){
    foreach( $array as $element )
        if( is_callable( $element ) ) 
           ....
}
```